# How to reliably determine that an entity is transient?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

With NHibernate, how does one reliably check that a given entity is transient (i.e. hasn't been persisted yet)?  The resources I have seen recommend something similar to this:

```
public bool IsTransient()
{
    return this.Id == default(Guid);
}
```

Assuming my **already persisted** entity has an integer ID and it is somehow equal to 0, wouldn't this method fail?

Comment: Before you write a new record do database the ID has a 0 value and is "Transient". Its not possible that you have an integer ID not 0 when this object is not persisted yet, unless you set it manually. Normally when you save to database with an "Insert" statement the record gets automatically an autogenerated ID and that ID is copied in the object. After that the object is not "Transient" anymore but "Persisted". So when your record is saved to Database the object will always have a ID value not 0 and is regarded as "Persisted".

Comment: You can have auto generated keys that start at 0 though. At least with SQL Server. So the code and the DB has to follow the same convention.

Comment: I don't know what you are exactly saying but what I know about IsTransient it checks if an ID = 0. If thats the case the object is Transient and not Persisted yet to database. Its just a checking method. Thats the convention. Its like you already pointed: "i.e. hasn't been persisted yet"

Comment: You can have persisted data with ID = 0 if you don't enforce it in the DB. Thus my confusion and original question (in 2011). The answer cleared up things for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 0 is a valid primary key in your context, then yes, that would be unreliable.

Basically, the "unsaved-value" on the id of the object determines if it's transient or persistent. By default, it's set to null or default() for the type. You can choose to set this manually when you do your mapping.

As long as your logic in the code above conforms to what Nhibernate believes is a transient object, you're good. And Nhibernate will take any object whose Id property equals that of "unsaved-value" to be transient.

Comment: I don't know if  "unsaved-value" is right. The IsTransient function is mostly used to check if an object is already saved to database. The checking is mostly done on the primary key (ID). Good design says the Primary key cannot be changed. If you save the object to database you get the newly created ID back. It is placed in the ID property of the object. That ID is already saved and will not be saved again.